# plink to execute passwd command in linux

Tags: fedora, plink

i am using a window batch file and execute plink.exe to access to my fedora ftp server. It is successful. Now i created a user by useradd command with password. But it is unable to login as by default is disable and need to use the `passwd` command to change the password and able to login. But using plink, how to make something like this??`

`passwd testing`
`myPassword`
`myPassword`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass the `-p` option to `useradd` instead of trying to change the password after the fact.

From `man useradd`

```
 -p, --password PASSWORD
          The encrypted password, as returned by crypt(3). The
          default is to disable the account.
```

Using -p you will need to have the password encrypted beforehand.  Also, see [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150882/how-to-automatically-add-user-account-and-password-with-a-bash-script/2150937#2150937) which provides similar answers and a script to generate the hashed password dynamically.

Comment: thanks for the reply,
in my situation, i am using Window batch file to do it,how?
and is it necessary to use the Python script??

Comment: thx anyway i solve it by using 2 batch file